# Getting to work GetAuthTicketForWebApi in Steamworks.net (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I want to authenticate Unity game client with Steamworks.net to connect account with my Node.js server by using SteamUser.GetAuthTicketForWebApi. Howhever I cannot get a callback from that function. In my code example Debug.Log("callback") never appear.
Commands like SteamUser.GetSteamID() or SteamFriends.GetPersonaName() are working correctly. But not SteamUser.GetAuthTicketForWebApi.

I tried to do this on a newly created project. All steps i have done, Should I have done something else?:

1. new project
2. adding authentication in package manager
3. set up App Id and Key in Authentication project settings
4. adding steamworks.net in package manager
5. setting up my app id in steam_appid.txt
6. add game object with SteamManager.cs in scene
7. add game object with that code:

```
using Steamworks;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using UnityEngine;

public class SteamUtility : MonoBehaviour
{
    Callback<GetTicketForWebApiResponse_t> m_AuthTicketForWebApiResponseCallback;
    string m_SessionTicket;
    string identity = "unityauthenticationservice";

    private void Start()
    {
        
        SignInWithSteam();
    }



    void SignInWithSteam()
    {
        // It's not necessary to add event handlers if they are 
        // already hooked up.
        // Callback.Create return value must be assigned to a 
        // member variable to prevent the GC from cleaning it up.
        // Create the callback to receive events when the session ticket
        // is ready to use in the web API.
        // See GetAuthSessionTicket document for details.
        m_AuthTicketForWebApiResponseCallback = Callback<GetTicketForWebApiResponse_t>.Create(OnAuthCallback);

        
        SteamUser.GetAuthTicketForWebApi(identity);
        Debug.Log("login");
    }

    void OnAuthCallback(GetTicketForWebApiResponse_t callback)
    {
        Debug.Log("callback");
        m_SessionTicket = BitConverter.ToString(callback.m_rgubTicket).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        m_AuthTicketForWebApiResponseCallback.Dispose();
        m_AuthTicketForWebApiResponseCallback = null;
        Debug.Log("Steam Login success. Session Ticket: " + m_SessionTicket);
        // Call Unity Authentication SDK to sign in or link with Steam, displayed in the following examples, using the same identity string and the m_SessionTicket.
    }

}
```

Comment: is it not returning some form of token it expects you to include in further communicaitons? thats how a lot of things work

Comment: It doesn't look like it